# BibTeX-Thesis supervisor

Tags: bibtex

I am new in `BibTeX` and I would like to ask a question. I want to define entry supervisor to a thesis like this:

```
@thesis{ID,
author = {author},
title = {name},
year = {year},
address = {Brno},
type = {type},
pages = {pages},
school = {school},
supervisor = {supervisor},
}
```

The result should look like this: Author. Name. Adress, year, pages. Type. School. "Thesis supervisor" (string) Supervisor (entry).

The code of the function looks like this:

```
FUNCTION {thesis}
{ output.bibitem
format.authors "author" output.check
new.block
format.btitle
"title" output.check
new.block
address "address" bibinfo.check output
format.date "year" output.check
format.thesis.pages output
new.block
bbl.bcthesis format.thesis.type output.nonnull
new.block
school "school" bibinfo.warn output
new.block
format.doi output
new.block
format.url output
new.block
format.note output
}
```

Can please to have an help to implement it the style file?

Comment: You can use the optional `note` field. By the way, is the thesis supervisor a needed detail?

Comment: I've never before come across thesis bibliographic items that listed the supervisor(s) of somebody's thesis. Are you concerned that their could be two (or more) John Smiths out there who each wrote a thesis with the exact same title and year from the same university -- necessitating a `supervisor` field in order for readers to differentiate between them?

Comment: It's not a needed detail, but I would like to used it.